# Getting a position from a touch even in Javascript

Tags: javascript, touch

Pretty simple question: I am observing an element in Javascript on an iPad, and I want to know where is the user's finger when he moves it over my element.

I am using the touchstart and touchmove events. From Mozilla's documentation, it doesn't seem like what I'm looking for exist. But I'm probably wrong.

After all. I am merely looking for an equivalent to the event.offsetX property from a mousemove event.

Do anyone know how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me provide a small primer:

With touch events you have access to two different touch event lists: the touch target list and the changed touches list.

The touch target list provides a list of all of the current touch targets.  So if you have 3 fingers on the touch screen, you will have 3 touch targets.  The number of touch targets supported by a device is device dependent.

The changed touches list is the list of targets that have changed state in some way for the current event like moving or ending.

Rather than provide code here, I recommend taking a look at this [site](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents.shtml) to get a basic idea of how to get touch coordinates.  There are a number of other sites available through a simple Google search that provide other tutorials and code snippets for accessing other touch event data.

Also, [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/) is a link to the W3C page on touch events.  Best of luck to you.

Comment: It doesn't look like Webkit from iOS implements touch events that way. The touchmove event doesn't even send a TouchEvent object.